# Calculating the sum of a variable within all children (recursive)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a model as follows:

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model):
  parent = ndb.KeyProperty()
  someint = ndb.IntegerProperty(default = 2)
  sum_of_child_some_int = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

The **parent** property is either nothing (in the case of a top level parent) or is a Key pointing at another **SomeModel** entity.

My question is, what is the most efficient way of calculating the sum of all the **someint**'s of all children of a **SomeModel** parent? It is recursive, so a child can itself have a child, and the **someint** would also need to be counted.

I see that it can be done at write - simply write to the entities parents recursively. But can it be done at read, or is that always going to be too expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to put that number at write time, you could use an ancestor query to get all the children of a given entity and extract the **someint** property. If you are going to do this, I think the most efficient way would be to use [projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries).

Just remember that if you don't write that sum when you put the entity, you will have to make the sum every time it is requested (although you may get a cached result), which sounds a bit wasteful. Memory is cheap, and adding another property updated at write time seems like the best idea to me.

By the way, maybe you don't need the parent as a KeyProperty, an [ancestor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor) may be a better way to do it.